# Click on Invisible link

Tags: xpath

click on 10th hidden link in amazon.in site

I tried in eclipse using selenium-java language with xpath of 10th element

```
package chaitanya;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Kc11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "E:\\kittu\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver p=new ChromeDriver();
        p.get("https://www.amazon.in");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        p.findElement(By.xpath("//a[10]"));
        Thread.sleep(6000);


    }

}
```

I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

Error talks about the element is not reachable/intractable, this might be due to below reasons,

1. **Element is hidden**   **OR**
2. **Other element is displayed over that
   element**

First try to bring element into view and then perform the operation, you can use JavaScriptExecutor to bring element intoView,

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'})", element);
```